# In GCP, having issues while create autoscaling signal in instance group with "Metric export scope" = "Single time series per group" with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a compute managed instance group and trying to autoscale it using custom metrics with terraform. The issue I am facing is that when i am provisioning  the resource, in autoscaling signal (in instance group) it is taking "Metric export scope" as "time series per instance"   but I want it to be "Single time series per group". I tried  a lot couldn't found any way to achive this.

What I am getting

[image]

What I am trying to achive

[image]

This is my terraform code below:-
main.tf:-

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "mig-template" {
  name           = "${lower(var.environment)}-${var.service_name}-launch-template${var.name_suffix}"
  machine_type   = var.machine_type 
  can_ip_forward = false
  metadata_startup_script = var.startup_script 
  tags           = ["nomad"]

  disk {
    source_image = data.google_compute_image.debian_buster.id
    auto_delete = true
    disk_size_gb = var.disk_size_gb
    device_name = "xvda"
  }

  network_interface {
    network = data.google_compute_network.my-network.id
    subnetwork  = data.google_compute_subnetwork.my-subnetwork.id
  }

  service_account {

    email  = google_service_account.nomad_service_account.email
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }

  labels = merge(var.default_tags,
      {
        a_type   = var.type
        environment = var.environment
        autoscale   = "true"
      }
  )
}

#creating custom metrics
resource "google_monitoring_metric_descriptor" "cpu_metrics" {
  description     = "Unallocated CPU for nomad instances"
  display_name    = "nomad_client_unallocated_cpu"
  type            = "custom.googleapis.com/${var.telegraf_namespace}/nomad_client/unallocated_cpu"
  metric_kind     = "GAUGE"
  value_type      = "DOUBLE"
  unit            = "MHz"
  metadata {
    sample_period = "60s"
    ingest_delay  = "30s"
  }
}

#creating custom metrics
resource "google_monitoring_metric_descriptor" "memory_metrics" {
  description     = "Unallocated CPU for nomad instances"
  display_name    = "nomad_client_unallocated_memory"
  type            = "custom.googleapis.com/${var.telegraf_namespace}/nomad_client/unallocated_memory"
  metric_kind     = "GAUGE"
  value_type      = "DOUBLE"
  unit            = "MBy"
  metadata {
    sample_period = "60s"
    ingest_delay  = "30s"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_region_instance_group_manager" "group_manager" {
  name = "${lower(var.environment)}-${var.service_name}-instance-group${var.name_suffix}"

  base_instance_name         = var.instance_base_name
  region                     = var.region
  distribution_policy_zones  = var.distribution-policy-zones 

  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.mig-template.id
  } 

}

resource "google_compute_region_autoscaler" "auto_scaler" {
  depends_on = [google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.group_manager]
  name   = "${lower(var.environment)}-${var.service_name}-autoscaler${var.name_suffix}"
  region   = var.region
  target = google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.group_manager.id

  autoscaling_policy {
    max_replicas    = var.max_replicas
    min_replicas    = var.min_replicas
    cooldown_period = 600

  metric {
    name = google_monitoring_metric_descriptor.cpu_metrics.type
    target = "2500"
    type = "GAUGE" 
    }
  metric {
    name = google_monitoring_metric_descriptor.memory_metrics.type
    target = "1000"
    type = "GAUGE" 
    }
  }
}

Module:--
---------

module "nomad_client_europe-central2" {
    source                    = "./modules/nomad_client"
    template_subnetwork       = "private-subnet-1"
    machine_type              = "e2-medium"
    compute_image             = "debian-buster-base-1677584808"
    startup_script            = file("./mig_user_data/bootstrap.sh")
    distribution-policy-zones = ["europe-central2-a", "europe-central2-b","europe-central2-c"]
    min_replicas              = 2
    max_replicas              = 4
    telegraf_namespace        = "Telegraf_NomadClientMIG"
    name_suffix               = "-abcd"
}
```

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, rather add errors as text and any code as well as reproducible blocks of code.

Comment: @MarkoE well Its not an error, but have just showed the option my code should select in the screen shot.  If you could suggest something.? have went through whole terraform doc, but no luck.